# Для чего используется # (##) в url?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Никак не могу понять для чего используются `#` или `##` в MVC проекте. Нажимаю кнопку и получаю url вида `http://localhost:55555/example/exm/List##`

Comment: первый # - начало хэша, второй - содержимое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ссылка вида `http://localhost:55555/example/exm/List##` состоит из двух частей:

1. **Адрес**, куда надо выполнить переход. Если совпадает с текущей страницей, никакого перехода не выполняется.

   В данном случае это `http://localhost:55555/example/exm/List`.
2. **Якорь**, меченое место на странице, куда производится отмотка после перехода.

   Якорем является всё после первого символа решётки; в данном случае это второй символ `#`. Значит, должна произойти отмотка до `<a name="#"></a>`, либо `<div id="#">...</div>`.

Если при нажатии на ссылку происходит появление всплывающего окна с формой, значит нажатие на данную ссылку перехватывается JavaScript-обработчиком события `onclick`. Тогда адрес ссылки не имеет никакого значения; он срабатывает только при выключенном JavaScript и, должно быть, ведёт на запасную форму на отдельной странице.

Comment: _он срабатывает только при выключенном JavaScript и, должно быть, ведёт на запасную форму на отдельной странице._ - каким образом он может вести на запасную форму на отдельной странице если адрес меняется только `#`?

Comment: @Grundy, значит, одно из двух: либо производится отмотка на форму на той же странице, а сама форма изначально видима, но скрывается скриптом; либо скрипт сам извлекает якорь и делает определённые действия на основании его значения. Касательно втогого могу сказать точно: [это **не** MVC-ный *routing*](//stackoverflow.com/a/5567773/2553424).

Comment: @Grundy, `если адрес меняется только #` — это при условии, что у автора ссылка была вида `href="##"`, о чём он прямо не говорил.

Comment: второе невозможно, так как перед этим ты сказал, что скрипты отключены

Comment: @Grundy Псевдокласс `:target` позволяет делать вкладки или диалоги на чистом HTML+CSS без скриптов :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну так это ж псевдо класс, а не скрипт :-)

Comment: @Grundy и как это мешает ему активировать запасную форму на текущей странице? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так что речь выше шла именно о скрипте, плюс _запасная форма на отдельной странице_.

Answer (score 2):

Если интересно, то вот в кратком изложении общая схема URI (Universal Resource Identifier) (URL (Uniform Resource Locators)).

```
/* 
   https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI 
   RFC 3986
   URI = [ схема ":" ] иерархическая-часть [ "?" запрос ] [ "#" фрагмент ]

   ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
    12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9

  // ? Ноль или одно    
  // * Ноль или более
  // + Одно или более

    группа 2 — схема,
    группа 4 — источник,
    группа 5 — путь,
    группа 7 — запрос,
    группа 9 — фрагмент.

    URL:
    <схема>://<логин>:<пароль>@<хост>:<порт>/<URL‐путь>?<параметры>#<якорь>

    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier -
    - A generic URI is of the form:
    [scheme:][//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]

    The following figure displays two example URIs and their component parts.

                    hierarchical part
        ┌───────────────────┴─────────────────────┐
                    authority               path
        ┌───────────────┴───────────────┐┌───┴────┐
  abc://username:password@example.com:123/path/data?key=value#fragid1
  └┬┘   └───────┬───────┘ └────┬────┘ └┬┘           └───┬───┘ └──┬──┘
scheme  user information     host     port            query   fragment

  urn:example:mammal:monotreme:echidna
  └┬┘ └──────────────┬───────────────┘
scheme              path    

*/
```

Как следует из нее, интересующий вас `#` это содержимое части URI, называемой *фрагмент* (или *якорь* в терминологии URL).

На практике URL и URI  часто взаимозаменяемые термины. Хотя, разница между ними есть (цитата [отсюда](http://citforum.ru/internet/xml/uri/))

> Термин "унифицированный указатель информационных ресурсов" (URL)
>   относится к подмножеству URI, которые, помимо идентификации ресурса,
>   указывают способ его нахождения путем описания основных механизмов
>   доступа к нему (т.е. его "положение" в сети).

Как именно интерпретируется фрагмент, зависит от исполнителя URI/URL. В принципе его можно рассматривать как еще один не структурированный аргумент (остальные аргументы передаются в части URI, называемой *запрос*)

Answer (score 0):

Обычно при разработке в ссылках делают заглушки (в href выставляют значение #)

Comment: Это явно не заглушка - появляется форма редактирования

Comment: Ну я часто видел ссылки, которые ссылаются на ту же страницу с # в конце, при этом само действие при нажатии обрабатывается через JavaScript. В частности ссылка "добавить комментарий" ниже работает именно так.